# How can I determine the format of an ssh private key file?

Tags: ssh, private-key, openssh

I am developing an application that uses ssh keys (JSch), and it won't accept some ssh keys. I want to make guidelines to users so they know which keys they can use and which one they can't. Hence the question: how can I determine the format of an ssh private key file, going beyond the RSA/etc and the number of bits?

For instance, at the end of this question is a 3072 bit RSA key that was generated using `ssh-keygen` with no parameters on android/termux. it works in `ssh` but both JSch and JuiceSSH refuse to even open it. `openssl rsa -text -noout -in file` says:

> unable to load Private Key
>   1991864336:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY

I can fix this by running `ssh-keygen -p -m PEM -f file`, and this might be a workaround for some users, but it would help to know in advance which formats work and which don't.

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: Did you look at the SSH RFCs?

Comment: @JamesKPolk there's a lot of text in there, do you have anything specific in mind?